# What is this notation in the definition of an exterior derivative?

Tags: algebraic-topology, notation, definition, differential-forms

What does this notation inside the red boxes mean?  Is it a product of $a$'s and $\alpha$'s, or is it just a single element in it's respective set with the comma separated indexes to specify it's relation to each $e_i$?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not a product. It is a single member of $A$, indexed by a [multi-index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-index_notation). Although the subscript is written without commas in the cited page, you could certainly think of it with commas separating the subscripts. Since a basis for the module of tensors or wedges carry multiple basis elements for $M$, we need multiple indexes.

For example, if $M$ has basis $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$, then a basis for $\Lambda^2 M$ is $\{e_1\wedge e_2,e_2\wedge e_3,e_1\wedge e_3\}.$ So an arbitrary element $a\in\Lambda^2 M$ may be written $a= a_{12}\,e_1\wedge e_2+a_{23}\,e_2\wedge e_3+a_{13}\,e_1\wedge e_3.$ So $a_{12}$ just means the coefficient of the basis element depending on $e_1$ and $e_2$.

Comment: So $\sum a_{i_1 \dots i_p} e_{i_1} \land \dots \land e_{i_p}$ is essentially $\sum (a_{i_1, \dots , i_p}, e_{i_1}, \dots, e_{i_p})$?   (Essentially meaning by isomorphism with free group)

Comment: @OliverG No, there are some linear conditions which distinguish the free group (or module) on tuples of the $e_i$ from the tensor or wedge products. For example, in the free module, $(e_1,2e_2)$ and $(2e_1,e_2)$ are distinct pairs, but in the tensor product $e_1\otimes 2e_2 = 2e_1\otimes e_2$ and similarly for the wedge. In addition, the wedge product has an antisymmetry imposed. However the tensor products, symmetric products, and wedge products can be, and usually are, realizes as quotients of the free module on all tuples by the linear conditions one wishes to impose.

Comment: So instead of how you put it "$e_1\wedge e_2$ is essentially the pair $(e_1,e_2)$ in the free module", I would instead say "$e_1\wedge e_2$ is the equivalence class of the pair $(e_1,e_2)$ in the quotient of the free module by the linearity conditions for tensor and antisymmetry"

Comment: I'm not sure I understand now, what exactly is being summed for $\sum a_{i_1, \dots i_n} e_{i_1} \land \dots \land e_{i_p}$?  Normally an index is written in but I don't understand exactly what's being summed.

Comment: @OliverG $\sum a_{ij} e_i\wedge e_j = a_{12}\,e_1\wedge e_2+a_{23}\,e_2\wedge e_3+a_{13}\,e_1\wedge e_3.$

Answer (score 1):

Each $a_{i_1,\dots,i_p}$ is just a function, the coefficient of $e^{i_1} \wedge \dots \wedge e^{i_p}$, hence the notation. No products understood.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of $a_{i_1 \cdots i_p}$ as instead $a_{i_1, \cdots, i_p}$ (where I've used commas), or as $a(i_1, \cdots, i_p)$ (where I'm expressing $a$ as a function of the indices). But the comma-omitted version is perhaps most popular. It's reminiscent of the iterated derivative notations $f_{xy}$ or $D_{xy}$ often used to refer to two consecutive partial derivatives (and not a single derivative with respect to $xy$ or something like that).